# python UDP socket client need to send twice so that the server can receive the package

Tags: python, sockets

i have a client will send some string to my server. However, i need to send twice so that the server get the package. So for every package client wants to send the server, it needs to send twice. I do not understand why it went in this way.

my server's code that does listening:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
myIp = "0x2A"
myPort = 2222
targetPort = 0
myAddress = ("localhost",myPort)
bufferSize = 1024

def listen():

    print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*myAddress))
    sock.bind(myAddress)
    # sock.listen(1)
    print("waiting for message")
    # connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    while True:

        received = sock.recvfrom(bufferSize)[0]
        address = sock.recvfrom(bufferSize)[1]
        received = json.loads(received.decode()) 
        source = received.get("source")
        destination = received.get("destination")
        length = received.get("length")
        message = received.get("message")
        protocol = received.get("protocol")

        print("the source is: " + source)
        if destination == myIp:
            print("the message is: " + message)
            print('sending back to sender...')
            sock.sendto(message.encode(),address)

            if protocol == 0:
                print("protocol is: " + str(protocol))
            elif protocol == 1:
                print("protocol is: " + str(protocol))
                print("write data to log file....")
                f = open("log.txt","w")
                f.write(message)
                print('done!')

            elif protocol == 2:
                print("protocol is: " + str(protocol))
                # sock.close()
                print("exit")
                sock.close()
                sys.exit()
        else:
            print("this is not my package: \n" + "destination Ip is: " + destination + "\n my Ip is: " + myIp)

        if not received:
            break
```

my client's code that does the sending:

```
def send():
    try:
        sock.sendto(message.encode(),serverAddress)
        print("message: " + message +  " is sent")
    finally:
        print('closing socket')
        sock.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    received = sock.recvfrom(bufferSize)[0]
    address = sock.recvfrom(bufferSize)[1]
```

The first `recvfrom` will do the first read. The second `recvfrom` will do another read. Voila: you need two reads. Instead you should do a single read:

```
    received, address = socket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
```